# Can all integers be written as a difference of two powers of integers?

Tags: number-theory

I have recently been trying to find representations of small numbers. On the form:

$c = a^n - b^m$, where $a, b, n, m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

There are obviously an infinite number of trivial cases if we allow $n, m = 1$. So omitting these trivial solutions, I found that there are no non-trivial solutions for e.g. $c = 6, 14, 42$, when $a,b \leq 1000;\ n,m \leq 20$.

If there actually do not exist any solutions, what numbers have the same property?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, see the related [Pillai's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Pillai's_conjecture), where the table there for "... solutions for perfect powers less than $10^{18}$" indicates there are none known for $c = 6, 14, 42$, as you've already indicated, plus there's also currently none for $c = 34, 50, 58, 62$. As indicated there, see [OEIS A076427](https://oeis.org/A076427) and [OEIS A103953](https://oeis.org/A103953) for additional details.

Comment: If $c$ is odd, we can express $c$ as the difference of two square. If $c$ is divisible by four, again two squares will work. So this leaves the case $c\equiv 2\pmod 4.$

Comment: The only solved case is actually difference $1$ , for which $(8,9)$ is the only pair.